# Is it possible to recover temporary uploaded files (not moved with move_uploaded_file()) after script execution?

Tags: php, upload, temporary-files, tmp

I have some php scripts that handle uploaded files via forms and stores them using move_uploaded_files(). Because of errors in my code, some uploaded files were not handled properly and were not moved, i.e. they got lost.

I thought that within a reasonable grace period (i.e. few days) I may be able to find them in the /tmp/ folder which is where they are temporarily stored when uploaded. But the files don't seem to be there any more.

I guess there's no way to recover them is it? But I've noticed some strange "socket" files in that folder (such as sso_main.phpapi.socket-0 and the like, all 0-byte) so I'm wondering if there is any hope the files may have actually been stored somewhere else...

Or are they deleted *immediately* after script execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.